# VNC connection to Xorg window

Tags: x11, remote, vnc

I have a computer with an attached display starting a Java application via `startx`.

Now I want to access the application remotely via VNC. Is it possible to open a `x11vnc` session for one Xorg window? (Without window manager)

```
# x11vnc -display :1
12/11/2019 13:31:53 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 2759
No protocol specified
12/11/2019 13:31:53 XOpenDisplay(":1") failed.
12/11/2019 13:31:53 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
No protocol specified

12/11/2019 13:31:53 ***************************************
12/11/2019 13:31:53 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:1)

*** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":1", it cannot continue.
*** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
```

```
/bin/sh /usr/bin/startx /usr/bin/java -jar my.jar -- :1
 \_ xinit /usr/bin/java -jar my.jar -- /usr/bin/X :1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.XruRNQHDLk
      \_ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :1 -auth /tmp/serverauth.XruRNQHDLk
     \_ /usr/bin/java -jar my.jar
```

Edit: I found out, that running the `startx` command without my systemd service works perfectly fine with x11vnc.
Now I struggle to attach the x11vnc server to my systemd startx service.

Comment: What user is the startx running as? Also root?

Comment: Yes startx is running as root.

Comment: All the processes you can see are running as root

Answer (score 0):

You can add `x11vnc` to `~/.xinitrc` or, even better, to `~/.xsession`.

Comment: Thanks you. I edited the initial post because the problem shifted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the systemd service. I changed my service to start with the `runuser` command. (Both `x11vnc` and `startx`)